# Difference between binary search tree and m-way tree

Tags: algorithm

Please explain the difference between a binary search tree and m-way tree?

Answer (score 7):

An m-way tree is a tree structure that has `m` values and `m + 1` links.

A binary tree is a special case of an m-way tree with `m` equal to one, meaning only one value per node and two links (you either move down to the left or the right link). Here's an example of a binary tree that shows this:

```
             +----+
             | 20 |
             +----+
            /      \
      +----+        +----+
      | 14 |        | 23 |
      +----+        +----+
```

An m-way tree can have more than one value per node but the theory is still the same. You choose which link to move down to based on the values, and there's `m + 1` possible choices. An m-way tree (where `m` is 2) may look like this:

```
              +----+----+
              | 17 | 30 |
              +----+----+
       ______/     |     \______
      /            |            \
+----+----+   +----+----+   +----+----+
| 11 | 15 |   | 19 | 28 |   | 33 | 34 |
+----+----+   +----+----+   +----+----+
```

These m-way trees are often used in situations where you can fit more than one value in an efficient block. By efficient, I mean one that can be read and written efficiently, like a disk block, sector, cluster or cylinder depending on how your storage subsystem operates.

For example, let's say that:

- a disk block is 512 bytes;
- the values in your tree take up 122 bytes; and
- the links take up 4 bytes.

In this situation, you can fit 4 values into a disk block, calculated as follows:

```
numvals = int ((blocksize - linksize) / (valuesize + linksize))
        = int ((   512    -     4   ) / (   122    +     4   ))
        = int (          508          /            126        )
        = int (                    4.0317                     )
        =                             4
```

That gives you four values and five links for a total of 508 bytes:

```
4 * 122 = 488
5 *   4 =  20
          ---
          508
```

Although there's some wastage (four bytes in this case), this has the advantage of storing an integral number of values in each efficiently-retrievable block.

Answer (score 2):

A [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) has only two fixed branches and is therefore a lot easier to implement. m-way trees such as [B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) are generally used when the tree has to be stored on disk rather than in memory. Examples include file systems and database indexes.

Answer (score 0):

an m-way search tree is a m-way tree in which:

Each node has m children and m-1 key fields
The keys in each node are in ascending order.
The keys in the first i children are smaller than the ith key
The keys in the last m-i children are larger than the ith key

An extension of a multiway search tree of order m is a B-tree of order m. This type of tree will be used when the data to be accessed/stored is located on secondary storage devices because they allow for large amounts of data to be stored in a node.

A B-tree of order m is a multiway search tree in which:

The root has at least two subtrees unless it is the only node in the tree.
Each nonroot and each nonleaf node have at most m nonempty children and at least m/2 nonempty children.
The number of keys in each nonroot and each nonleaf node is one less than the number of its nonempty children.
All leaves are on the same level.